# How to access the elements between zero th index and date index from sublist in python3?

Tags: python

How to access the elements between zero th index and date index  from sublist in python3?

Find element between zero th index and date index.
After that , concat those elements. and keep in a list.
After that insert the concat elements to first index in a sublist and remove splitted elements.

```
import re
nested_list =[["1","a","b","22/01/2014","variable"],["2","c","d"], 
["3","e","f","23/01/2014","variable"]]
sub_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(nested_list)):
    concat = ''
    data_index = ''
for j in range(0,len(nested_list[i])):
    temp = re.search("[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{4}", nested_list[i][j])
    if temp:
        date_index = j              
if date_index:
    for d in range(1,date_index):
        concat = concat+' '+ nested_list[i][d]
    print(concat)
```

Expected Output:

```
nested_list =[["1","a b","22/01/2014","variable"],["2","c","d"],["3","e f","23/01/2014","variable"]]
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do and where you have a problem. Also you wrote the same paragraph twice. Try to simplify and rewrite your question a little.

Comment: i remove the paragraph which is repeated and find the elements of the sublist between date and zeroth element

Comment: why is `["2","c","d"]` not combined to `["2","c d"]` ?

Comment: why do you import `datatime` - you do nothing with it?

Comment: i want the elements between date and zeroth index thats why  ["2","c","d"]  i didnt combine these elemen t@ Patrick Artner

Comment: sorry by mistake i add the line import datetime but now i edited that line @PatrickArtner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you

> want the elements between date and zeroth index thats why ["2","c","d"] i didnt combine these elemen t@ Patrick Artner

Here you go:

```
import re
nested_list =[["1","a","b","22/01/2014"],["2","c","d"], ["3","e","f","23/01/2014"]]

result = []
for inner in nested_list:
    if re.match(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}",inner[-1]):  # simplified regex
        # list slicing to get the result
        result.append( [inner[0]] + [' '.join(inner[1:-1])] + [inner[-1]] )
    else:
        # add as is
        result.append(inner)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'a b', '22/01/2014'], ['2', 'c', 'd'], ['3', 'e f', '23/01/2014']]
```

---

**Edit** because dates might also occure in between - what was not covered by the original questions data:

```
import re
nested_list =[["1","a","b","22/01/2014"], ["2","c","d"], 
              ["3","e","f","23/01/2014","e","f","23/01/2014"]]

result = []
for inner in nested_list:
    # get all date positions
    datepos = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(inner) 
               if re.match(r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}",value)] 

    if datepos:
        # add elem 0
        r = [inner[0]]
        # get tuple positions of where dates are
        for start,stop in zip([0]+datepos, datepos):
            # join between the positions 
            r.append(' '.join(inner[start+1:stop]))
            # add the date
            r.append(inner[stop])
        result.append(r)
        # add anything _behind_ the last found date
        if datepos[-1] < len(inner):
            result[-1].extend(inner[datepos[-1]+1:])
    else:
        # add as is
        result.append(inner)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['1', 'a b', '22/01/2014'], 
 ['2', 'c', 'd'], 
 ['3', 'e f', '23/01/2014', 'e f', '23/01/2014']]
```

Comment: thank ypu so much but the date position is not fixed it may vary

Comment: yes sir thanks i edited my question please see my code again i want to add elements between date and zeroth index and keep other elements in the list as it is @ Patrick Artner

Comment: only one time date appeared in the sublist sir @Patrick Artner

Comment: @uday does not matter - it works for one or more. it adds all elements after the last found one. check it against your data.

Comment: thank you so much sir...for this clear solution...even my professor wont teach me like this ...thanks a lot sir@ Patrick Artner